# How Can we display blocked area for particular timeline in horizontal bar in gantt highchart

Tags: highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

[image]

I am using gantt highcharts in my angular application. In Gantt highcharts, I need to display blocked area(stripped lines) for particular timeline in horizontal bar in gantt highchart (which are highlighted in red color). tried many solutions but didn't get the solutions. Kindly help.

Comment: I don't know what those lines are, it's rendered?  Could you show it in a simplified demo example?

Comment: Sebastian, these lines are basically displaying the task is blocked for the particular time. Just need to draw in bar. Unfortunately there is no as such demo for this, only have the image which need to achieve... the JS fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/hr260389/cy4z637k/ which in current development.

Comment: Here, you can also try rendering the background on point with this patern filling on the background.

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Can you please provide a demo for the same, as I am trying this but not succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to add pattern fill to rendered background, remember to join to your scripts, script responsible for pattern.
`<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>`

```
    chart.myBackground = chart.renderer.rect(plotLeft + 10, plotTop, firstPointWidth - 20, 50, 0)
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 1,
        stroke: 'red',
        fill: {
          pattern: {
            path: {
              d: 'M-1 1 l2 -2 M0 16 l16 -16 M15 17 l8 -8',
              strokeWidth: 2,
              zIndex: 6
            },
            color: 'black',
            width: 16,
            height: 16
          }
        },
        opacity: 0.5,
        zIndex: 5
      })
      .add();
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mhL5c824/